# Write a command to display text file name and its size in different lines in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to display text file name and its size in different lines

I have tried

```
du *.* | cut -f 1
```

This give me only size of the files in given directory

```
du *.* | cut -f 2
```

This gives the filenames

But i could't figure out how to format it in way where the size comes first then the file name.

example :

```
4
file1.txt 
5
file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out this is working as expected.

```
du *.txt* | tr [:space:] '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some awk scripting:

```
for file in *
do
echo "$file $(du "$file" | awk '{print $1}')"
done
```